# IF statement interpolation

Tags: excel

Could anybody tell me what is wrong with the below formula? I think it is something to do with a comma but not sure. Continuously get an error with this.

```
=IF(S2="customer”,”551”,IF(S2=“business”,”552”,IF(S2=“both”,”551, 552”, “”)))
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting? I just tried it and it worked. But, you have closing quotes around your True part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are somehow using quotes that are not recognized by Excel (if the formula you are using is the **exact same** as the one you posted).

For example, notice how `“”` (from your formula) is different than `""` (the accepted characters).

As others have stated, this works: `=IF(S2="customer","551",IF(S2="business","552",IF(S2="both","551, 552", "")))`

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Out of interest, how do you switch between the different forms of quotes?

Comment: @user6222395 it really depends on what you are doing. What did you do to create that formula in Excel? Did you copy-paste it from somewhere else or did you type it straight into a cell?

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a non-US locale you may need to use semicolons `;` instead of commas `,`. Try with `;` instead of `,`

```
=IF(S2="customer";551;IF(S2="busines2";552;IF(S2="both";"551,552";"")))
```

This works in my excel table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
=IF(S2="customer","551",IF(S2="business","552",IF(S2="both","551, 552", "")))
```

Comment: How is this different out of interest? At a glance it looks identical so it would be really useful if you could call out exactly what the problem was and what the fix was and why it works...

Comment: If you copy the OP's statement into Excel, a formula error pops up. I did explain above in the comment that they have closing quotes (fancy quotes) around their true parts, so there is no open quotes. I changed them to straight quotes on both sides. My bad for not explaining in more detail in my answer.

Comment: Ah, so you've changed the "smart quotes" into standard quotes? Still think it would benefit from actually explaining that in your answer rather than expecting people to read comments elsewhere.

Comment: Agreed... future reference noted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error are you getting? I put it in as the below and all 4 returns work correctly. Looks the same as yours to me but here it is to be on the safe side.

=IF(S2="customer","551",IF(S2="business","552",IF(S2="both","551, 552","")))